# Populate a remote databse using MySQL Workbench and remote .sql file

Tags: backup, restore, mysql

I'm using MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE, and I try to figure out how to populate or restore a

> mysql_dump.sql

file uploaded to the root of my domain (./mysql_dump.sql).

Since the file is a little bit big (700MG) I wanted to restore it in a fast way, rather than using phpMyAdmin or Ozerov's BigDump.

I have shell access to the server through SSH, and I can connect to it using putty.  But is there an easier way to do it using workbench? I'm not a super advanced database admin, just a beginner who trying to learn something ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database doesn't exist yet on the server create it in MySQL Workbench. Then run this command in the shell:

```
mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#
```

It will prompt you for your database user password.

Comment: thank you citadelgrad,
I accomplished this using putty and SHH. still didn't find a way to do it on workbench.